# Ordinary Least Squares Regression for multiple columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to find a way to iterate code for a linear regression over many many columns, upwards of Z3. Here is a snippet of the dataframe called df1

```
    Time    A1      A2      A3      B1      B2      B3
1   1.00    6.64    6.82    6.79    6.70    6.95    7.02
2   2.00    6.70    6.86    6.92    NaN     NaN     NaN
3   3.00    NaN     NaN     NaN     7.07    7.27    7.40
4   4.00    7.15    7.26    7.26    7.19    NaN     NaN
5   5.00    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     7.40    7.51
6   5.50    7.44    7.63    7.58    7.54    NaN     NaN 
7   6.00    7.62    7.86    7.71    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

This code returns the slope coefficient of a linear regression for the very ONE column only and concatenates the value to a numpy series called series, here is what it looks like for extracting the slope for the first column:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

series = np.array([]) #blank list to append result

df2 = df1[~np.isnan(df1['A1'])] #removes NaN values for each column to apply sklearn function
df3 = df2[['Time','A1']]
npMatrix = np.matrix(df3)
X, Y = npMatrix[:,0], npMatrix[:,1]
slope = LinearRegression().fit(X,Y) # either this or the next line
m = slope.coef_[0]

series= np.concatenate((SGR_trips, m), axis = 0)
```

As it stands now, I am using this slice of code, replacing "A1" with a new column name all the way up to "Z3" and this is extremely inefficient. I know there are many easy way to do this with some modules but I have the drawback of having all these intermediate NaN values in the timeseries so it seems like I'm limited to this method, or something like it.

I tried using a for loop such as:

```
for col in df1.columns:
```

and replacing 'A1', for example with col in the code, but this does not seem to be working.

Is there any way I can do this more efficiently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### One liner (or three)

```
time = df[['Time']]
pd.DataFrame(np.linalg.pinv(time.T.dot(time)).dot(time.T).dot(df.fillna(0)),
             ['Slope'], df.columns)
```

[image]

#### Broken down with a bit of explanation

Using the closed form of OLS

[image]

In this case `X` is `time` where we define `time` as `df[['Time']]`.  I used the double brackets to preserve the dataframe and its two dimensions.  If I'd done single brackets, I'd have gotten a series and its one dimension.  Then the dot products aren't as pretty.

[image]

is `np.linalg.pinv(time.T.dot(time)).dot(time.T)`

`Y` is `df.fillna(0)`.  Yes, we could have done one column at a time, but why when we could do it altogether.  You have to deal with the `NaN`s.  How would you imagine dealing with them?  Only doing it over the time you had data?  That is equivalent to placing zeroes in the `NaN` spots.  So, I did.

Finally, I use `pd.DataFrame(stuff, ['Slope'], df.columns)` to contain all slopes in one place with the original labels.

**Note** that I calculated the slope of the regression for Time against itself.  Why not?  It was there.  Its value is 1.0.  Great!  I probably did it right!

Comment: Works great. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Looping is a decent strategy for a modest number (say, fewer than thousands) of columns. Without seeing your implementation, I can't say what's wrong, but here's my version, which works:

```
slopes = []

for c in cols:
    if c=="Time": break
    mask = ~np.isnan(df1[c])
    x = np.atleast_2d(df1.Time[mask].values).T
    y = np.atleast_2d(df1[c][mask].values).T
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
    slopes.append(reg.coef_[0])
```

I've simplified your code a bit to avoid creating so many temporary `DataFrame` objects, but it should work fine your way too.

Comment: Ahh this was driving me crazy, thanks for the quick fix!